# File not found error on setting background image using img src attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change background of an element with id = "image" using source attribute of an image in the html. The source is an absolute url on the web and its loading perfectly at other places of html.

The problem is in the last line of the code. previewPic is an image object that I am passing to this javascript code.

I have created a var x to see if I am getting the src correctly and thats working fine. I am seeing correct in the console.
I have already tried different combinations of "x" "url(x)" etc.

```
function upDate(previewPic) {

    var x = previewPic.src; 

    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = previewPic.alt+" "+x;

    console.log(x);

    document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = "url(x)";

}
```

File not found error.

Comment: what is `previewPic` ? whats its value

Comment: previewPic is the image element that I am passing to this javascript code.

Comment: yes I am able to see the correct output in the console which is the url I want.

Comment: First hard code the value here `"url(x)"`
check if it is found 
the image is it in root folder ?

Comment: Hard coding the value changes the image to desired one but what do you mean by root folder here?